# AVR8 assign bit in assembly

Tags: avr, assembly

I want to simply assign (copy) a bit in the IO register from some other register bit (or flag, or as a result of some comparison). Now I am using following (`PORTD[2] := r0[3]`):

```
    sbrc r0, 3      ; Skip if Bit in Register is Cleared
    sbi  PORTD, 2   ; Set Bit in I/O Register
    sbrs r0, 3      ; Skip if Bit in Register is Set
    cbi  PORTD, 2   ; Clear Bit in I/O Register
```

But is it optimal? Is there better way? How to make it with other sources - some flag for example C or T?

Comment: If it doesn't matter if the I/O-pin briefly toggles  (when it is already low and it is to stay low), then you could remove the first `sbrc`.

Comment: One trick is to write the code in C, then check if the compiler comes up with a smart trick that you didn't think of yet.

Comment: @jippie, glitches in the output are not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On many AVRs, this can be made faster (but not smaller) via the status register's T bit:

```
bst  r0, 3      ; Store bit 3 of r0 into T
in   r2, PORTD  ; Read the current value of PORTD
bld  r2, 2      ; Load bit 2 of r1 from T
out  PORTD, r2  ; Write the updated value back to PORTD
```

This requires only 4 cycles (vs. 5: either 2+0+1+2 or 1+2+2+0) and always updates `PORTD` at the fourth cycle regardless of the bit value.

### Caveats:

- If an ISR updates `PORTD` between the `in` and `out` instructions, that update will be reverted by the `out`.
- Another CPU register is required if `r0`'s value must be preserved (`r2` in this example, but it can be any).
- XMEGA and Reduced Core AVR devices have single-cycle `cbi` and `sbi` instructions, so there's no speed difference on those targets.